# Multi Level Inheritance giving error if define in reverse order in OOPS PHP

Tags: php, oop

I am trying to test Multi level inheritance using 3 classes in reverse order as define below, giving me error of Class B not found.

```
class A extends B
{
  function area_a(){echo "A::hello";}
}
 class B extends C
{
    function area_c()
    {
        echo "hiiii";
    }
  function area_b(){echo "B::hello";}
}
 class C
{
     function area_c(){echo "C::hello";}
}
$obj=new A;
$obj->area_b();
```

Comment: change order of to class C,B,A

Comment: I know that changing order works but Its not about the changing the order its work up to two level but not more then two

Answer (score 0):

It should work this way:

```
 <?php 
  class C {
     function area_c(){echo "C::hello";}
  }
  class B extends C{
     function area_c(){
        echo "hiiii";
     }
    function area_b(){echo "B::hello";}
  }

  class A extends B{
    function area_a(){echo "A::hello";}
  }



  $obj=new A;
  echo $obj->area_b();
```

Regarding the error, when the code is compiling, then it goes to `class A` and checks that it extends `class B` and searches above for `class B` and can't found, hence the error.

Comment: class A extends B
{
  function area_a(){echo "A::hello";}
}
 class B
{
    function area_c()
    {
        echo "hiiii";
    }
  function area_b(){echo "B::hello";}
} it works without changing order

Comment: @NareshRamoliya If you take class C at the top then it works